# MapBox. Hide layer at custom style

Tags: gis, mapbox, geojson

I have two tileset with coordinate (created from GeoJSON file):

- tilest # 1. Point on map.
- tilest # 2. Route on map.

Both tilesets are so big - so, I don't what to make client to download data source and filter it.

I've created custom Mapbox style and added two layers with these tilesets as data sources.

I want to show the map from style:

- without these custom layers
- with only first layer
- with only second layer
- with both layers

Is it possible to do with Mapbox Static API (https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#static)? Or mapbox caches and makes rasterisation from all layers in style and separate them is not possible?

In general, what is the best strategy for huge tilesets? Should I make different style for every case and switch them on client?